# Do you know any valuable alternative to XML_Serializer which is up-to-date?

Tags: php, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm in need to serialize object into XML and XML_Serializer should do that, however, the version is still in beta, not much active (no activity since 2010-10) and still depends on PHP4.

I'd rather avoid to write such tool myself, so may you know an alternative?

Comment: Well, representing an object (and its sub-objects) in XML form is pretty easy actually, we're talking about a single recursive function. It's not like you were going to map objects to a relational database... ;)

Comment: yeah I agree, but depending on the object it can be messy. XML_Serializer stores types, visibility, etc.. and instantiante a new object previously serialized.

Answer (score 0):

http://querypath.org/ is actively developed.  https://github.com/technosophos/querypath

It is much more advanced (broader focus...), but seems to be a really useful tool.

Comment: Could you give an example of serializing an object with QueryPath? I didn't find anything about serialization in QP doc.

Answer (score 0):

A library that offers an XML representation of serialized objects is [**Serialized**](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized).

Writing an XML Serializer for PHP objects (and other values) is as easy as:

```
/**
 * XML object serializer
 */
function XML_Serialize($object)
{
    require_once('/path/to/Serialized.php');
    $parser = new Serialized\Parser(serialize($object));
    return $parser->getDump('XML');
}
```

Unlike [`XML_Serializer` <sup>**PEAR Package**</sup>](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer/redirected) this is one-way so far. However you have specifically written *"I'm in need to serialize object into XML"*, so I'm not entirely sure if you really need to unserialize from XML as well. This can be done by parsing the XML into the array notation of serialized which should be quite trivial.

After that's done, the only thing left is to call the Serialized dumper on that array structure and unserialize the output.